# Show data in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to show DB data using Vuejs. I want to show some product codes. It shows well as I expected. I want to show now description instead of code. But when I try it other prices and all things are changing.

I have mentioned below tried code ->

```
<template v-for="(chosen_configuration, index) in quote.chosen_configurations">
    <td colspan="3">
      <select id="configuration" name="configuration" v-model="quote.chosen_configurations[index]">
        <option v-for="configuration in quote.configurations" v-text="configuration.configuration_code"></option>
      </select>
    </td>
</template>
```

I want to show `configuration.description` instead of `v-text="configuration.configuration_code"` But when I try `v-text="configuration.description"` it not workes.

How can I show data using `configuration.description` without changing `v-text="configuration.configuration_code"`. Is that possible ?

Comment: What exactly you want to display? `<option></option>` has two required attributes, `value` and `text`. Ex. `<option value="test">Test</option>`

Comment: What do you mean by all things are changing? It is nice that you provided the code but we lack the context or the data model, do you have a sample js object or json to show that?

Comment: Isn't `<option v-for="configuration in quote.configurations" v-text="configuration.description"></option>`  what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am adding the code you need, If we understood exactly your request. If it is what you're looking for, accept it as a solution.

```js
<template v-for="(chosen_configuration, index) in quote.chosen_configurations">
  <td colspan="3" :key="index">
    <select id="configuration" name="configuration" v-model="quote.chosen_configurations[index]">
      <option v-for="(configuration, j) in quote.configurations" :key="j" v-text="configuration.description" :value="configuration.configuration_code"></option>
    </select>
  </td>
</template>
```